# Speed of swig wrappers

Tags: c++, python, performance, swig

If I were to write several classes in c++ then use swig to do the conversion so I could later use them in python, would they run faster or slower than if I completely rewrote them in python? Or is there no noticable speed difference?

Comment: It depends. You can make some tests/measurements or describe in detail your classes. Good written C++ classes can be a tens faster than python one. And sometimes, good python JIT can outperform bad-written C++ code.  The wrapper itself is very fast.

Comment: So the wrapper provides relatively native speed? It doesn't hamper any of the performance?

Comment: The overhead will be rather small for simple objects and will grow for big data structures, which must be copied element by element from one format to another in the wraper.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The quality and speed of wrappers generated by SWIG is very good, and they will probably perform just as good as handcrafted wrappers.

From my experience, the wrappers themselves are very thin and add very little overhead to the native functions they wrap, making it a perfectly valid choice to use wrapped libraries in python or any other supported language, and is a good way to reuse code.

however, to be if you are interested in performance in addition to code reuse, wrapping native code will probably only pay off if you have some computationally intensive native functions, like multiplying matrices, computing MD5 or CRC, folding proteins etc.

on the other hand, sometimes you can just rewrite everything in an easy language like python or C# and enjoy better code and better tools, with comparable performance.